# How to show debug console on flutter devtool

Tags: flutter

Flutter provide a tool call devTool for debug, but if i log something like `print("Abc")`, it will appear on debug console like this (here is vscode)
[image]

But how can i show that in devtool, for example i want to logs tons of receive data from api, it will be mess if log on small screen like this

I want to show the error here
[image]

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use debug console for viewing logs ?

Comment: I think it somehow too small, for example vscode, it take space and it will be great if we can log on devtool